# driver poll function wait on all waitqueues

Tags: linux, driver

From the linux device drivers book, I understand that a device driver implementing a poll function would call poll_wait then return a bit mask corresponding to which operations can be completed immediately.

I also understand that poll_wait can be called multiple times for different wait queues, and if any of these wait queues are woken up, the user space application that originally called poll/select would also be woken up.

Is there a way to prevent the kernel from waking up the application until all the wait queues added by the driver are woken up?

Comment: you don't want to introduce behavior different from the documented one to the kernel. leave it in user space.

Comment: well that's definitely something I want to avoid. I can't handle this in user space though. I have a driver that could be receiving multiple interrupts and want the user space code to be able to make a poll/select call that will wait for 1 or more of these interrupts where the number of interrupts are determined by previous ioctl calls. I was hoping there was an easy way to do this in the driver such that it would have to wait on all waitqueues added to the poll_table.